# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, servlets

Am trying to initialize JSONObject in my servlet

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    UserInfoBean ui= getInfo(empId);

    try{
        obj.put("ID", empId);
        obj.put("Name", empName);
        obj.put("Address", address);
        obj.put("Phone", phone);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}**
```

I have added json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar in my project. Right Click on the project -> BuildPath -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar .Then added that particular jar.

But still I get this error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [com.thirdAttempt.UserInformation] in context with path [/ThirdTry]
>   threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONObject  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     at com.thirdAttempt.UserInformation.doPost(UserInformation.java:48)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is found compile time but not runtime. I suggest you use maven or gradle for dependency management, that way you can specify what jars you want in your classpath like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: should I add these lines in the same web.xml?

Comment: You put this in pom.xml(if you use maven) but since your are not using maven you should follow these steps.  Add the jar file to your WEB-INF/lib folder.
Right-click your project in Eclipse, and go to "Build Path > Configure Build Path"
Add the "Web App Libraries" library

Comment: At least in my case, I also needed to add <classifier>jdk13</classifier> or <classifier>jdk15</classifier>.